# Overload operator>> in self-made class 'String' C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I am creating class 'String'.

But I have a problem with overloading of operator>>.

I've tried to do like this:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& input, String& inputStr)
{
    char str[] = "";
    input >> str;
    inputStr.size = strlen(str);
    inputStr.str = new char[inputStr.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.size; i++)
    {
        inputStr.str[i] = str[i];
    }
return input;
}
```

But it doesn't work =(

Can you help me to overload this operator ?

Here is a code:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class String
{
private:
    int size;
    char* str;

public:
    String();
    ~String();
    String(char* arr);
    String(const String& copy);
    int sizeStr();
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const String& outputStr);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, String& inputStr);
};

String::String()
{
    this->size = 0;
    this->str = nullptr;
}

String::String(char* str)
{
    this->size = strlen(str);
    this->str = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        this->str[i] = str[i];
    }
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] str;
}

String::String(const String& copy)
{
    if (this != &copy)
    {
        this->size = copy.size;

        this->str = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = copy.str[i];
        }
    }
}

int String::sizeStr()
{
    return this->size;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const String& outputStr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < outputStr.size; i++)
    {
        output << outputStr.str[i];
    }

    return output;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& input, String& inputStr)
{


    return input;
}
```

I`m looking forward to your help.

Comment: `char str[] = "";` gives you an array of one character.  It will not be automatically resized for you.

Comment: So, what I need to do ?

Comment: It looks like in the language you're using there is already a powerful built in string type `char[]`. It apparently can resize itself on demand and manage its own memory. Why create a class?

Comment: I can't use standard string. It's a condition of this task.

Comment: This is a pretty fun problem. You don't know how big the string is ahead of time, so you can't presize the buffer. Looks like you'll have to guess a reasonable size for your buffer and read into the buffer character by character until you find a whitespace delimiter, resizing the buffer when it fills up.

Comment: it isnt evening in 75% of the world at the moment :P

Comment: I looked at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream  and it has some unformatted input functions, which might be used to implement a http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction?